# Compilation error when trying to reference a CloudBlockBlob in blobstorage triggered function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Here's my function code.

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob"

public static async Task Run(CloudBlockBlob uploadedVideo, string name, CloudBlockBlob processedVideo, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {uploadedVideo.Length} Bytes");
    var fileEntry = new 
    {
        fileName = $"uploaded-videos/{name}",
        fileType = "video",
        correlationId = Guid.NewGuid()
    };
    await processedVideo.StartCopyAsync(uploadedVideo);  
    await uploadedVideo.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
}
```

and here is my function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "uploadedVideo",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "uploaded-videos/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "processedVideo",
      "path": "processed-videos/{name}-{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the error that it keeps throwing when I run this function.

> 2018-09-25T07:34:10.813 [Error] Function compilation error
>   2018-09-25T07:34:10.982 [Error] BlobTriggerCSharp.csx(2,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob' could not be found
>   2018-09-25T07:34:11.040 [Error] BlobTriggerCSharp.csx(4,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CloudBlockBlob' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   2018-09-25T07:34:11.128 [Error] BlobTriggerCSharp.csx(4,73): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CloudBlockBlob' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob` assembly, it's a namespace included in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`. The assembly and namespace should be used as below.

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

And `CloudBlockBlob` can't directly get Length property, we have to fetch blob properties first.

```
await uploadedVideo.FetchAttributesAsync();
log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {uploadedVideo.Properties.Length} Bytes");
```

Comment: I have the same issue but your solution is not fixing it.
Error goes as 
`2018-11-22T12:18:13.662 [Error] run.csx(118,19): error CS1061: 'CloudBlobContainer' does not contain a definition for 'Exists' and no extension method 'Exists' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudBlobContainer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
I have also check with Exit